# Vaadin & Firebase : Authentication with Fb when migrating to firebase.google.com

Tags: maven, firebase, vaadin

I've been working with Vaadin and Firebase for a few months. Now, the project is migrating from firebase.com to firebase.google.com  This means changing the dependencies in my ivy file. The problem is I cannot find the correct sdk. I used to be able to install the Firebase JVM Client Library from mvn, but that doesn't seem to have a homologue in com.google.firebase  The only SDK available in com.google.firebase is firebase-server-sdk, which doesn't include any means of authentification client-side. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no longer is a way to authenticate a specific user when accessing the Firebase Database from a (non-Android) JVM program. The code runs as a service account, which inherently has full access to the database.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/serverreference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth

We know that this excludes some use-cases and are considering adding this functionality into the JVM SDK in a future version. But as usual: no guarantees and no timelines.